# AMPscript <= not working correctly past a certain number

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm new to ampscript and generally only write it in line, so that might be my problem. However, when I use the code below in my SFMC email, OrderTotal values of 100+ are getting the "OrderTotal <= 70" message. OrderTotal values of ~71-90 are getting the ELSEIF message as they should. I also noticed this error when I used `ELSEIF (OrderTotal > "70") THEN]`

```
Don’t miss this special opportunity %%[IF (OrderTotal <= "70") THEN]%%to
apply your admission ticket(s), a %%=FormatCurrency(OrderTotal,"en-US",0)=%% value, 
toward the cost of an annual membership.%%[ELSEIF(OrderTotal >= "71") THEN]%% to 
apply $70 from the purchase of your admission tickets toward the cost of an 
annual membership.%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Comment: Assuming that your OrderTotal field is a number field, try removing the "" around your 70 / 71 values. That would indicate strings, and that would not really work with a greaterThan comparison. You need to have number / decimal fields for this. Also you can simplify the `ELSEIF` line by simply using `ELSE` without any specification, and without `THEN`.

Answer (score 1):

There are few issues with your code:

- You should prepend your variable names with "@", as this is the correct notation for variables. I assume you are fetching these numbers from your sendable data extension. In this case you should define your @OrderTotal using [AttributeValue](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/attributevalue.htm) function, making your code more robust.
- When comparing numbers, don't wrap them in quotation marks, as this makes them being treated as text strings
- As you only have two options (<= 70 and > 70) you can simply use ELSE

```ampscript
SET @OrderTotal = AttributeValue("OrderTotal")
Don’t miss this special opportunity %%[IF @OrderTotal <= 70 THEN]%%to
apply your admission ticket(s), a %%=FormatCurrency(@OrderTotal,"en-US",0)=%% value, 
toward the cost of an annual membership.%%[ELSE]%% to 
apply $70 from the purchase of your admission tickets toward the cost of an 
annual membership.%%[ENDIF]%%
```

It might be worth mentioning, that your solution can be simplified slightly, bu using the [inline IF function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/iif.htm), although it will give you less control over the text. But perhaps it can prove handy in different context:

```ampscript
Don’t miss this special opportunity to apply 
%%=IIF(@OrderTotal <= 70,FormatCurrency(@OrderTotal,"en-US",0),"$70")=%% 
from the purchase of your admission tickets toward the cost of an annual membership.
```